# Fastest Ubuntu version for development

Tags: ubuntu, slowdown

I'm using Ubuntu for development. Today I installed the new 11.04. Boot time is almost twice/three times as fast. Also I do not really need all the fancy graphics as I want to focus on developing web apps and desktop/console apps.

I now read that with every release Ubuntu tends to slow down a bit and many people claim it's bloated. In your experience, which version of Ubuntu is the fastest?

Thanks,
Frank

(PS: If you have an idea for a better OS than Ubuntu pls let me know. One of Ubuntu's strong points to me is the integration of Synaptic though, which sets everything up for me so I don't have to waste time on configuration.)

Comment: I have just found a website where they compare boot times: http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu_natty_boot&num=3 .. also I upgraded and did not do a fresh install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are correct, Ubuntu is quite bloated. If you plan to use it for development I recommend Fedora; I am sure many others will agree with me on this.

You may have to take some additional time to setup everything the way you want it, but you will be happier in the long run.

http://fedoraproject.org/

Comment: Thanks Dennis, what do you think of Arch linux?

Comment: Also, do these distributions have sth like a package manager as Ubuntu does?

Comment: Fedora if I don't get wrong is Gnome based, it would be quite the same.

Comment: Arch Linux is another good one which focuses on simpleness, elegance, and speed - unfortunately I haven't had too much playing time with it to give you a solid review.   Fedora offers packages via http://rpmfusion.org/

Comment: Check this out - perfect for you. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/from-ubuntu-to-fedora-landing-on-foreign-soil-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly/       Let me know what you think as I am using Ubuntu as well and plan to switch some time soon.

Comment: Although I haven't used a RedHat-based product in years, there's no way I would switch back from a Debian-based system. Ubuntu is only as bloated as you want it; it's almost trivial to slim it down. Given that Fedora is based on much of the same core software as Ubuntu (linux kernel, gnome/kde) I don't think you'll find a substantial difference. Most importantly to me, I think that despite the introduction of yum, package management is still way better in Ubuntu/Debian.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to listen to someone telling something related to IT is "slow" or "fast". It's a dramatic simplification that never helps you understand what are your needs and the relative solutions to choose. How many times we heard "Java is slow", and this is plain false for many reasons.

I can bet Ubuntu 11.04 "standard" will run fine in your machine, also for development. You wouldn't notice any sensible performance boost installing other versions (maybe Xubuntu would be like 6-7% faster), neither by installing other Gnome-based distros.

BTW, is your Ubuntu 11.04 installation made from scratch or by updating a previous version?

Just disable visual effects, but in that case too you won't notice more than a insignificant performance improvement.

And no, Ubuntu is not bloated at all, it's a common place. And it's strange that the boot time increased so much, you should read what happens in the boot process, maybe there's something strange going on.

Comment: Thanks Giacomo, I was using 10.10 and usually disable all the effects because I do not need them. Somehow it feels though as if the interface in 11.04 has gotten slower as well. I did not actually measure it, but the menus and windows seem to be slower :-/ I tried Unity 2D but that did not improve anything so I'm now with the basic Ubuntu/no effects login version..

Comment: I dislike Unity, for usability reasons before than on performance ones. If you disable fancy GUI effects, Ubuntu 11.04 will be as fast as 8.10.

Comment: Do you install the server edition and then add what you need or do you go straight ahead installing the desktop edition??

Comment: On a (very) slow machine I installed the server edition and then added a basic graphical environment, but later on I discovered that for development I needed a lot of facilities I had to install, and would have got immediately if installed the desktop version. What are the actual system characteristics?

Comment: I'm using a Dell XPS M1530 with a Duo Core @ 2.5 GHz and 4 GB of RAM. As I said, 10.10 in my opinion just seemed fine. Now it takes twice as long to boot which is odd.

Comment: It's really, really odd. The system is good, and Ubuntu 11.04 boots lightning fast on a poor netbook I have got. So, is it yours a clean install or an upgrade? Have you tried debugging the boot process?

Comment: Hmm.. I upgraded. Maybe I should try a clean install. I read however, that the Upgrades should not be a problem and are usually the same unless you really did some reconfiguring of the system yourself. Anyway, thanks for your help Giacomo!